# От символа до переноса или конца строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо выделить все строки, начинающиеся с символа `*` и продолжить выделение до конца или переноса строки. Пример:

```
*Тест
Ещё тест
*Ещё один
```

В результате должно получиться следующее:

```
<b>*Тест</b>
Ещё тест
<b>*Ещё один</b>
```

`.replace(/\*(.+?)\n/g, '<b>$1</b>')` работает только для переноса строки, но не её окончания. `.replace(/\*(.+?)$/g, '<b>$1</b>')` наоборот, только для окончания. Как совместить?

Comment: `(/\*(.+?)(\n|$)/g` не пробовали?

Comment: @andy.37 Да, это сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярное выражение может быть таким (это совместимо с PCRE):

```
/\*(.+?)(?:\n|$)/g
```

или таким (многострочный режим):

```
/\*(.+)$/gm
```

А еще можно воспользоваться особенностью регулярных выражений в JS- метасимвол точки никогда не совпадает с переносом строки:

```
/\*(.+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example code](https://codepen.io/):

```
const text = `
- Gigawatt hours of energy storage
    Explanation: Tesla's energy storage deployment reached nearly four gigawatt hours in Q1, with the expectation that stationary storage growth will significantly exceed vehicle growth.
    Key points:
        - Tesla's energy storage business is growing as a percentage of the company's revenue.
        - The company is making progress on storage profitability, generating its highest gross profit yet in Q1.
        - Tesla plans to continue investing heavily in its energy business, including the MegaPack product and the energy storage business.
        - The company plans to remain focused on cost efficiency and working capital to keep the business financially healthy.

- Gigawatt hours of energy storage
    Explanation: Tesla's energy storage deployment reached nearly four gigawatt hours in Q1, with the expectation that stationary storage growth will significantly exceed vehicle growth.
    Key points:
        - Tesla's energy storage business is growing as a percentage of the company's revenue.
        - The company is making progress on storage profitability, generating its highest gross profit yet in Q1.
        - Tesla plans to continue investing heavily in its energy business, including the MegaPack product and the energy storage business.
        - The company plans to remain focused on cost efficiency and working capital to keep the business financially healthy.
`;

const splits = text.split(/\n\s{0,}\n/g);
const result = splits.map((_text) => {
  return _text
    .replace(/-(.*)/, '<h4>$1</h4>')
    .replace('Explanation:', '<strong>Explanation:</strong>')
    .replace(/(Action points:|Key points:)/, '<p><strong>$1</strong></p><ul>')
    .replace(/\.?\s{2,}-(.*)/g, '<li>$1</li>') + '</ul>';
})
.join('');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), каким образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос.